# how to hide the particular column header of datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a datagrid with many columns, where some columns have a header and some columns don't have headers. I want a table like in the image:

[image]

The table in the image has 5 columns and the very first column has a header and the rest of the columns don't have headers.

Comment: you should add some what you already tried and sample code.

Comment: I tried by making headerVisibility to none.                                                                                        
 <DataGrid  HeadersVisibility="None"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridCoordinates,Mode=TwoWay}" >

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You can keep column's header property blank.

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMSSOURCE}" CanUserAddRows="false"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10">
     <DataGrid.Columns>

          <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding Path=PROPERTYNAME}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="COLUMN NAME" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding Path=PROPERTYNAME}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="COLUMN NAME" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding Path=PROPERTYNAME}" IsReadOnly="True"/>

      </DataGrid.Columns>

  </DataGrid>
```

Comment: i want datagrid with many columns, where some columns dont have header and some columns has header. like below image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewfoz.png

Comment: In this image, every column has header. Please try to brief you question and requirement then only someone can help you. You said you do not want headers in some columns and i provided an example. Please provide more information.

Comment: In image ,very first column has header named "flow capacity" and other columns don't have the headers ,but very first cell of each column has gray background which are editable. I just want to implement same table using datagrid.